NodeJS Express API timeout after 2 minutes
so I have my backend locally right now and I have an EC2 instance that has the API there. Timeout happens around 2 minutes after some request, my guess is that server.timeout is set to 2 minutes but I don't know how to change it in my code. To clarify things, the API is working perfectly with small amounts of data but as soon as I send like 500 requests and every one of them being 1 MB at least one of those 500 isn't done in 2 minutes so the API closes the socket (AT LEAST THAT'S WHAT I THINK ITS HAPPENING)
Code for the API:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '30mb'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }));

app.post('/calculate', async (req, res) => {
    POST CODE HERE
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port 3000`);
});

Here is how I'm sending a file/data: I have an array called batchRequests, which lets say at the moment will have 5 batch requests
batchRequests.push(fetch('ip/calculate', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({file}),
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
                }));

after this I send all batched requests concurrently with Promise
const batchResponses = await Promise.all(batchRequests);
requests.push(...batchResponses);

The error I'm getting on EC2 node is:
BadRequestError: request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:245:10)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at IncomingMessage._destroy (node:_http_incoming:224:10)
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:121:10)
    at IncomingMessage.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:83:5)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:797:9)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:791:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:338:12)

The erorr I'm getting locally is:
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
          ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
    at async Promise.all (index 9)
    at async D:\project\backend.js:49:32 {
  cause: SocketError: other side closed
      at Socket.onSocketEnd (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8280:26)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1589:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
    socket: {
      localAddress: '192.168.100.2',
      localPort: 62485,
      remotePort: 3000,
      remoteFamily: 'IPv4',
      timeout: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 2300660,
      bytesRead: 277
    }
  }
}

packages, just in case:
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  }

Node version: v20.14.0
I tried putting: res.socket.setTimeout(0); at the first line of the api post call but it didn't work.
